# Issue compiling PHP APC

Tags: php, web

I have downloaded the APC-3.1_9.tgz official version.

When I followed the steps:

1. tar -xzvf APC-3.1_9.tgz
2. cd APC-3.1_9
3. phpize
4. ./configure --enable-apc --enable-apc-mmap --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php (the command "**which php**" outputs **/usr/bin/php**)
5. make

I got the following error:

```
/bin/bash /tmp/APC-3.1.9/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/APC-3.1.9 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/APC-3.1.9/include -I/tmp/APC-3.1.9/main -I/tmp/APC-3.1.9 Usage: php [options] [-f] <file> [--] [args...] php [options] -r <code> [--] [args...] php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -R <code> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...] php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -F <file> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...] php [options] -- [args...] php [options] -a -a Run as interactive shell -c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory -n No php.ini file will be used -d foo[=bar] Define INI entry foo with value 'bar' -e Generate extended information for debugger/profiler -f <file> Parse and execute <file>. -h This help -i PHP information -l Syntax check only (lint) -m Show compiled in modules -r <code> Run PHP <code> without using script tags <?..?> -B <begin_code> Run PHP <begin_code> before processing input lines -R <code> Run PHP <code> for every input line -F <file> Parse and execute <file> for every input line -E <end_code> Run PHP <end_code> after processing all input lines -H Hide any passed arguments from external tools. -s Output HTML syntax highlighted source. -v Version number -w Output source with stripped comments and whitespace. -z <file> Load Zend extension <file>. args... Arguments passed to script. Use -- args when first argument starts with - or script is read from stdin --ini Show configuration file names --rf <name> Show information about function <name>. --rc <name> Show information about class <name>. --re <name> Show information about extension <name>. --ri <name> Show configuration for extension <name>.  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/APC-3.1.9/apc.c -o apc.lo
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `/bin/bash /tmp/APC-3.1.9/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/APC-3.1.9 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/APC-3.1.9/include -I/tmp/APC-3.1.9/main -I/tmp/APC-3.1.9 Usage: php [options] [-f] <file> [--] [args...] php [options] -r <code> [--] [args...] php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -R <code> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...] php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -F <file> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...] php [options] -- [args...] php [options] -a -a Run as interactive shell -c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory -n No php.ini file will be used -d foo[=bar] Define INI entry foo with value 'bar' -e Generate extended information for debugger/profiler -f <file> Parse and execute <file>. -h This help -i PHP information -l Syntax check only (lint) -m Show compiled in modules -r <code> Run PHP <code> without using script tags <?..?> -B <begin_code> Run PHP <begin_code> before processing input lines -R <code> Run PHP <code> for every input line -F <file> Parse and execute <file> for every input line -E <end_code> Run PHP <end_code> after processing all input lines -H Hide any passed arguments from external tools. -s Output HTML syntax highlighted source. -v Version number -w Output source with stripped comments and whitespace. -z <file> Load Zend extension <file>. args... Arguments passed to script. Use -- args when first argument starts with - or script is read from stdin --ini Show configuration file names --rf <name> Show information about function <name>. --rc <name> Show information about class <name>. --re <name> Show information about extension <name>. --ri <name> Show configuration for extension <name>.  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/APC-3.1.9/apc.c -o apc.lo '
make: *** [apc.lo] Error 1
```

Comment: Install the `php-pecl-apc` package from your distro's repository if available (e.g. `yum install php-pecl-apc` for CentOS/RHEL) - tends to have a much higher success rate if you don't require the latest version or non-default customizations.

Answer (score 2):

php-config should point at...php-config, not php.

Answer (score 2):

I would install APC with: `pecl install apc`

Unless you really need to use the source.

Comment: Sometimes you really need to install from the source.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for your answers. The solution was:

Use this line: ./configure --enable-apc --enable-apc-mmap

instead this: ./configure --enable-apc --enable-apc-mmap --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php

Problem fixed.